# Is it possible to query for the job schedule description?

Tags: sql-server-2012, jobs

Working on putting together a script to analyze all of the active jobs and I have nearly everything I need, but if possible I would like to be able to query for the schedules description as well. Is this possible? I am able to query for the name and ID out of `msdb.dbo.sysschedules` but it doesn't seem to have the schedules description. Where can I find this information?

Comment: Are you set on only using T-SQL? Because it's likely that what you're trying to do can be achieved with a couple lines of PowerShell using the `dbatools` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sp_help_jobschedule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-jobschedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which returns the `schedule_description` by calling another system proc, `sp_get_schedule_description`.

```
exec sp_help_jobschedule @job_name = 'Your Job Name', @include_description = 1
```

It'd probably be faster to roll this in a cursor instead of breaking apart that system proc which

Answer (score 1):

The description is not actually a value stored in the database. It is dynamically derived from the values in dbo.sysschedules. As per scsimon's answer, you can user sp_help_jobschedule, or just use sp_help_schedule within a cursor to get the description.

something like this.

```
    CREATE TABLE #tmp
(schedule_id            INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
 schedule_uid           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
 schedule_name          SYSNAME NOT NULL,
 enabled                INT NOT NULL,
 freq_type              INT NOT NULL,
 freq_interval          INT NOT NULL,
 freq_subday_type       INT NOT NULL,
 freq_subday_interval   INT NOT NULL,
 freq_relative_interval INT NOT NULL,
 freq_recurrence_factor INT NOT NULL,
 active_start_date      INT NOT NULL,
 active_end_date        INT NOT NULL,
 active_start_time      INT NOT NULL,
 active_end_time        INT NOT NULL,
 date_created           DATETIME NOT NULL,
 schedule_description   NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 job_count              NVARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @id INT;

DECLARE c_sched CURSOR LOCAL
FOR SELECT schedule_id
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysschedules;

OPEN c_sched;

WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM c_sched INTO @id;

        INSERT INTO #tmp
        (schedule_id,
         schedule_uid,
         schedule_name,
         enabled,
         freq_type,
         freq_interval,
         freq_subday_type,
         freq_subday_interval,
         freq_relative_interval,
         freq_recurrence_factor,
         active_start_date,
         active_end_date,
         active_start_time,
         active_end_time,
         date_created,
         schedule_description,
         job_count
        )
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule @schedule_id = @id,
                                       @include_description = 1;

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0
            BREAK;

    END;

CLOSE c_sched;

DEALLOCATE c_sched;

SELECT *
FROM #tmp;
```